# JavaScript: Avoid 'this' in object constructor getting overwritten by event?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, this

I can't think of a straightforward title for this problem. I can explain it better with code:

```js
function Bar() {
 this.string = "something";
 this.event = function(e) {
  console.log("This should say something: " + this.string);
 }
}

var foo = new Bar();

window.addEventListener("mouseover", foo.event);
```

The problem is 'this.string' becomes undefined in 'this.event', because the event listener changes 'this' to refer to the event instead.

I need a way to get it to print "something" instead.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an arrow function instead so that the inner function does not acquire a new context for its `this`.

```js
function Foo() {
 this.string = "something";
 this.event = (e) => {
  console.log("This should say something: " + this.string);
 }
}

var bar = new Foo();

window.addEventListener("mouseover", bar.event);
```

Another option would be to explicitly bind the `this.event` function to the instantiated object:

```js
function Foo() {
  this.string = "something";
  this.event = function(e) {
    console.log("This should say something: " + this.string);
  }.bind(this);
}

var bar = new Foo();

window.addEventListener("mouseover", bar.event);
```

You could also bind it when you assign the listener:

```
window.addEventListener("mouseover", bar.event.bind(bar));
```

Comment: Thanks! I will probably use the second option because I can't use ES6

Comment: If at all possible, don't constrain yourself to writing in old versions of the language because of browser incompatibility - you'll make it easiest on yourself if you let yourself write in the latest and most elegant version of Javascript and then transpile it to be compatible with ancient browsers with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/) automatically during your build process.

Answer (score 3):

[**bind**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) foo with `foo.event`

```js
function Bar() {
  this.string = "something";
  this.event = function(e) {
    console.log("This should say something: " + this.string);
  }
}

var foo = new Bar();

window.addEventListener("mouseover", foo.event.bind(foo));
```

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know if you deliberately want to avoid this, but you can simply pass an anonymous function as a handler for the event and invoke `foo.event()` there.

You *can* use `bind()` and arrow functions as the other guys suggested, but you can simply do that as well.

```js
function Bar() {
  this.string = "something";
  this.event = function(e) {
    console.log("This should say something: " + this.string);
  }
}

var foo = new Bar();

window.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  foo.event();
});
```

This works because the event handler is called with its `this` pointing to the Window object. When `foo.event` *is* the handler, its `this` is overwritten. However, if you invoke it from an anonymous function, that anonymous function "absorbs" the listener’s `this` and when you call `foo.event()`, it works alright.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the given answers, this can also be done with a simple local variable.

*And as suggested, and when using Babel to compile e.g. this as an arrow function, this it what that will translate to.*

```js
function Bar() {
 var _this = this;
 this.string = "something";
 this.event = function(e) {
  console.log("This should say something: " + _this.string);
 }
}

var foo = new Bar();

window.addEventListener("mouseover", foo.event);
```